# Can we record screen in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am new to ionic and I want to create something like screen view recorder for both iOS and android platform. I searched a lot but was unable to find any cordova plugin for screen recording. I just want to know, what I am asking is feasible or not??

Answer (score 3):

For Android use [ionic-screen-recorder](https://github.com/kwangmeng/ionic-screen-recorder).

For Ios use [cordova-replay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-replay).

Use these two Cordova plugins and you can record the screen.

Comment: cordova-replay for ios doesnt work - does anyone know an alternative for ios?